# calling extern function without specify namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, extern

The code compile without error, I would like to know what's the different declaring extern function within and without namespace?

--a.h--

```
namespace mynamespace {
    extern void foo();
}
```

--a.c--

```
namespace mynamespace {
    void foo(){
        dosomething;
    };
}
```

Are there any concern that I should worry about when calling foo() without
specifying namespace?

```
#include "a.h"
int main(int argc char *argv )
    foo()
}
```

instead of

```
#include "a.h"
int main(int argc char *argv )
    mynamespace::foo();
}
```

Comment: *"Are there any concern that I should worry about when calling foo() without specifying namespace?"* Try it, you'll find out very quickly. The compiler will tell you what it thinks of your code.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik weird things is that my compiler did not show any warning or errors, I am using gcc-4.9 on debain.

Comment: The translation unit containing `main`, as shown, [cannot possibly compile](http://rextester.com/UQO84160). If it does, then either you also provide a declaration of `foo` in a global namespace, or you have `using namespace mynamespace;` or `using mynamespace::foo;` somewhere in your code you haven't shown.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. I didn't notice that `using namespace mynamespace;` is already defined somewhere else in other header file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `using namespace mynamespace;` is already declared in other header file. So if one file include header file, which have already defined `using namespace mynamespace;`, the current header file will also affected.